# Checkbox value with id in Angular 2

Tags: html, angular

How can I get check box value without additional Boolean variable in angular 2.

Basically I want to enable or disable input field based on check box selection. I can do this with the help of ngModel and boolean variable but I don't need ngModel at the same time I don't want to use ngModel also.

Comment: Please share what have you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a reference variable:

```
<input type="text" [disabled]="myCheckbox?.checked === false">
<input type="checkbox" #myCheckbox 
       checked="myCheckbox?.checked === true" 
       (change)="myCheckbox.checked = myCheckbox?.checked">
```

Link to [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-31z1f8?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.
    at viewDebugError (core.es5.js?de3d:8418)
    at expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (core.es5.js?

Comment: that is not related to this issue, some other error. Please post more code where you are getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="myCheckbox"> Check me !
<input type="text" [disabled]="myCheckbox" placeholder="Fill me !">
```

You will need to have at least one ngModel to enable/disable, and 2 to store the input value.